# List made from excel spreadsheet using pandas can't be edited by functions?

Tags: python, pandas, list, function

so I have used Pandas to create 2 lists of strings containing letters and numbers from 2 different excel spreadsheets. What I'm trying to do is iterate through one of the lists and see if each item exists in the other list. However, in one list the letters are uppercase and in the other they are lowercase (abc1234 vs. ABC1234). So I tried making a function to take in a list, and make every item in that list uppercase. It should work, but when I return the list and print it out item by item to test, nothing has changed.

Any ideas why this list can't be edited? I'm new to python so forgive me if this is a simple thing. Searched all over here and can't find anything about it.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

# functions

def make_upper(items):
    for item in items:
        item.upper()
    return items

def main():

    df = pd.read_excel(file.xlsx', sheet_name = 'sheet3')
    df2 = pd.read_excel('Assoc Info.xlsx', sheet_name = 'sheet1')

available = []
skill_group = []

for i in df2.index:
    if df2['CURRENTSTATUS'].iloc[i] == "On Assignment":
        available.append(df2['login_id'].iloc[i])


for i in df.index:
    if df['skill_name'].iloc[i] == "Skill1" \
    or df['skill_name'].iloc[i] == "Skill2" \
    or df['skill_name'].iloc[i] == "Skill3":
        if df['login_id'].iloc[i] not in skill_group:
            skill_group.append(df['login_id'].iloc[i])

make_upper(available)

for item in available:
    print(item)


main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling just `item.upper()` (assuming `item` is a string), only will return item in uppercase, but not change the value of item in items list. Do the following instead:

```py
def make_upper(items):
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        items[i] = str(item).upper()
    return items

items = list('something')
print('Before: {}'.format(items))
print('After: {}'.format(make_upper(items)))
```

**Output**:

```
Before: ['s', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'g']
After: ['S', 'O', 'M', 'E', 'T', 'H', 'I', 'N', 'G']
```

## Even Better: *Use List Comprehension*

If you at all want to use a custom-function:

```py
def make_upper(items):
    return [item.upper() for item in items]
```

Otherwise, use the list comprehension directly on **`available`**.

```py
available = [item.upper() for item in available]

for item in available:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Perfect! The custom function didn't work, which is curious, but list-comprehension did. Thank you!

Comment: @akantares I tried both custom functions and they both worked for me. Could you please try again and let me know? Thank you.

Comment: I realized I was just calling the function and not overwriting the old list with the new one that the function made. Sorry for the confusion, it's been a while since I've used python or even coded. Thanks for all your help!